# Ajustar altura é largura do Qr Coder usando o MessagingToolKit.QRCode C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Existe alguma forma de ajustar a altura é largura?
agradeço

```html
        public void GerarQrCode(string NomeImagem,string Data)
        {
            QRCodeEncoder encoder = new QRCodeEncoder();
            Bitmap img = encoder.Encode("www.teste.com.br");
            var path = Server.MapPath("~/Content/images/");
            img.Save(path + NomeImagem + ".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode tentar alterar a escala do `QR Code` gerado.

```
encoder.QRCodeScale = 1;
```

Lembrando que o "1" é referente a escala, em pixels, do código gerado.

Referência: [How to re-size QRCode image without losing resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30012323/4843158)

Tutoriais:

- [Create a QR Code with a Logo in ASP.Net C#](http://www.markhagan.me/Samples/Create-QR-Code-With-Logo-ASPNet)
- [Gerando códigos QR](http://imasters.com.br/linguagens/c-sharp/gerando-codigos-qr-zxing-e-messagingtoolkit-qrcode/?trace=1519021197&source=single)